# What to do when a user reposts a question repeatedly?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, users

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307212/build-tree-with-hclust-ctree-rpart-or-some-other-function) has been posted by this user multiple times. Each time, other users ask for clarification, why it's not a duplicate of [his earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274260/count-in-several-dimensions), etc. After enough comments have accumulated, he deletes the question, waits a few hours and then reposts the exact same question, effectively deleting the entire comment history.

What are we supposed to do with these questions and users?

Comment: Flag one of them for moderator attention. Use the "other" option, and write something similar to what you've written here. Assuming that the automatic question ban doesn't kick in first, they can escalate the issue more effectively than you can (e.g. by sending the user a message to stop doing that).

Comment: @CodyGray Okay, will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vote to close as duplicate or flag for moderator attention. and downvote perhaps.

The user will eventually be banned from asking questions, quite automatically.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks!